# Minha classe "PlayerBehavior" não está herdando a outra classe "CharacterBase"

Tags: c#, unity3d, herança

Eu não estou conseguindo acessar a classe `CharacterBase` do meu Script `PlayerBehavior`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public enum TypeCharacter{
    Priest = 0,
    Mage = 1,
    Paladin = 2,
    Warrior = 3,
    Archer = 4,
    Newbie = 5

}

public enum PlayerStates
{

    Movement

}



public class PlayerBehavior : CharacterBase
{


    private TypeCharacter type;

    private AnimationController animationController;

    /* State Machine*/
    private PlayerStates currentState = PlayerStates.Movement;
    //


    //*Movimentation*//
    private float speed;
    public float speedRun;
    public float runStaminaCost;
    public float speedDodge;
    public float dodgeStaminaCost;
    public float timeRecoverDodge;
    private float currentTimeStaminaRecoverDodge;
    public float speedWalk;
    public float rotateSpeed;
    private float horizontal;
    private float vertical;
    private CharacterController controller;
    private float currentStamina;
    private float maxStamina;
    public float staminaRecover;





    //*Attack*//

    private int currentAttack = 0;
    public float attackRate;
    private float currentAttackRate;
    private float rangeAttack;
    public int totalAttackAnimations;

    //*      *//

    //UI
    public UIController UI;



    new protected void Start () {

        base.Start ();

        PlayerStatsController.SetTypeCharacter (TypeCharacter.Newbie);
        currentLevel = PlayerStatsController.GetCurrentLevel();
        type = PlayerStatsController.GetTypeCharacter();


        basicStats = PlayerStatsController.instance.GetBasicStats(type);

        animationController = GetComponent<AnimationController>();
        speed = speedWalk;

        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();

        currentAttack = basicStats.baseAttack;

        base.Start();


        maxStamina = basicStats.baseStamina * basicStats.agillity;

        currentStamina = maxStamina;


    }

    new void Update()
    {
        base.Update();

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))

        {
            currentLife -= Random.Range(1, 30);
        }

        UI.SetLife(basicStats.startLife, currentLife);


    }

    void Update ()  {

        switch (currentState) {
        case PlayerStates.Movement:

            vertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
            horizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

            if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift) && vertical != 0) {speed = speedRun; 
                animationController.PlayAnimation (AnimationStates.RUN);}

            else { speed = speedWalk;
                if (vertical != 0)
                    animationController.PlayAnimation (AnimationStates.WALK);}



            controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            transform.Rotate(0, horizontal * rotateSpeed, 0);
            Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
            float curSpeed = speed * vertical;
            controller.SimpleMove(forward * curSpeed);

            /*Attack */ 
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                Attack (); }

            currentAttackRate += Time.deltaTime;
            break;


        }


}

    private void Attack()
        {

        if (currentAttackRate >= attackRate) {
            currentAttackRate = 0;
            animationController.CallAttackAnimation (currentAttack);
            currentAttack++;

            if (currentAttack > totalAttackAnimations) {
                currentAttack = 0;
            }
        }

            Ray rayAttack = new Ray (transform.position, transform.forward);

            RaycastHit hitinfo = new RaycastHit ();

            rangeAttack = basicStats.baseRange;

            if (Physics.Raycast (rayAttack, out hitinfo, rangeAttack)) {
                if (hitinfo.collider.GetComponent<DestructiveBase> () != null) {
                    if (hitinfo.collider != GetComponent<Collider> ()) {
                        hitinfo.collider.GetComponent<DestructiveBase> ().ApplyDamage (currentAttack);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
//Basics Atribuits//
public class BasicStats{
public BasicStats baseInfo;
public float startLife;
public float startMana;
public int strenght;          /*STR*/
public int intelligence;      /*INT*/
public int agillity;          /*DEX*/
public int concentration;     /*CON*/
public int baseDefense;
public int baseAttack;
public float baseRange;
public float baseStamina;
}

public abstract class CharacterBase : DestructiveBase
{

public int currentLevel;
public BasicStats basicStats;

// Use this for initialization
protected void Start () {

    currentLife = basicStats.startLife;


}
// Update is called once per frame
protected void Update()
{

}
```

}

Comment: E onde esta classe `CharacterBase` está definida?

Comment: Como assim ? Eu sou novo em programação ainda se tiver um pouco de paciência agradeço.

Comment: Você fez a classe `PlayerBehavior` herdar a classe `CharacterBase`, mas esta segunda não está definida no código. Pode colocar a implementação dela na pergunta e explicar melhor o quis quiser com "*não estou conseguindo acessar a classe*"?

Comment: da pra entender assim ?

Comment: a unity está acusando que o error está aqui basicStats = PlayerStatsController.instance.GetBasicStats(type); então quer dizer que o script não está herdando a classe character base para pegar o basicstats correto ?

Comment: qual erro que está dando ?

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: `PlayerStatsController` ou `PlayerStatsController.instance` ou `type` está nulo apenas, nada a ver com herança

Comment: e como resolvo isso ?

Comment: instanciando o objeto que estiver nulo =]

Comment: E como eu instacio um objeto nullo ? desculpa eu sou novo em programaçao esse script é de tutorial e estou modificando do meu jeito.